# При попытке исключить набор пользователем возраста буквами/спецсимволами, сообщение начинает бесконечно отправляться юзеру

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Пишу бота для Телеграма. На этапе запроса возраста всё вроооде бы хорошо, однако тест показал, что если вводить возраст не цифрами вопреки всему, а чем угодно ещё, то бот крашится и начинает транслировать "ЦИФРАМИ ПОЖАЛУЙСТА" пока не лопнет:

```
def get_surname(message):
    global surname
    surname = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Сколько тебе лет? Напиши цифрами')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_age)

def get_age(message):
    global age
    while age == 0: #проверяем что возраст изменился
        try:
            age = int(message.text) #проверяем, что возраст введен корректно
        except Exception:
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'ЦИФРАМИ, ПОЖАЛУЙСТА')
```

И теперь вот не знаю, что делать с этим( Помогите исправить, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Вы какую-то хрень написали, вы же из хендлера не выходите. Делать надо так.

```
def get_age(message):
    if message.text.isdigit():
        age = int(message.text)
        ...
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Неверный ввод.')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_age)
```

Comment: Это помогло выйти из цикла, но при этом бот крашится и срабатывает только после перезапуска

Comment: @ДаниилА. Эмм, может вы покажите хотя бы лог ошибки?